# Plotly.js multiple subplots not working as expected

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

Edit to add: Looking for the "plotly.js" way to do this. This "small multiple" visualization should have some "plotly.js" solution out there but haven't found it yet.

I am using an array (example element below) to populate `traces` for `plotly.js` multiple subplots per their [multiple-subplots example](https://plotly.com/javascript/subplots/#multiple-subplots)

```
[{
    "key": "Ontario|Toronto",
    "values": [{
        "key": "2020-01-25",
        "value": 1
    }, {
        "key": "2020-01-27",
        "value": 1
    }, {
        "key": "2020-05-12",
        "value": 218
    }, {
        "key": "2020-05-13",
        "value": 169
    }]
}, { 
    etc
}]
```

The array has 94 elements which contain info needed to create each trace. This would result in 94 subplots, one per trace. This `plotly.js` visualization could also be called "small multiples".

I am creating the `traces` dynamically and populating subplot definitions in a loop using code below:

```
// create chart data
var traces = [];
var rowCount = (caseRegionByDate.length / 2).toFixed()

for (var i=0; i<caseRegionByDate.length; i++) {
    //console.log(caseRegionByDate[i]['key']);
    var trace = {};
    var x = [];
    var y = [];
    for (var j=0; j<caseRegionByDate[i]['values'].length; j++) {
        //console.log(caseRegionByDate[i]['values'][j]['key']);
        x.push(caseRegionByDate[i]['values'][j]['key']);
        y.push(caseRegionByDate[i]['values'][j]['value']);
    }
    // create trace i
    trace = {
    "x":x,
    "y":y,
    "xaxis":"x"+i,
    "yaxis":"y"+i,
    "type":"scatter"
    }
    // push trace to traces
    traces.push(trace);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(traces));

var layout = {
    grid: {rows: rowCount, columns: 2, pattern: 'independent'},
    };

Plotly.newPlot('multiple_charts', traces, layout);
```

This creates the `traces` variable populated by each trace that looks like example below. It looks correct:

```
[{
    "x": ["2020-03-16", "2020-03-23", "2020-03-24", "2020-03-25", "2020-03-31", "2020-04-01", "2020-04-02", "2020-04-03", "2020-04-06", "2020-04-07", "2020-04-08", "2020-04-09", "2020-04-10", "2020-04-11", "2020-04-13", "2020-04-14", "2020-04-15", "2020-04-16", "2020-04-17", "2020-04-18", "2020-04-21", "2020-04-22", "2020-04-23", "2020-04-24", "2020-04-25", "2020-04-26", "2020-04-27", "2020-04-28", "2020-04-29", "2020-04-30", "2020-05-01", "2020-05-02", "2020-05-03", "2020-05-04", "2020-05-05", "2020-05-06", "2020-05-07", "2020-05-08", "2020-05-09", "2020-05-10", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-12", "2020-05-13"],
    "y": [1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 35, 3, 16, 33, 13, 9, 5, 5, 1, 22, 3, 4, 7, 19, 4, 7, 2, 18, 11, 9, 9, 9, 13, 1, 3, 7, 18, 5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2],
    "xaxis": "x0",
    "yaxis": "y0",
    "type": "scatter"
}, {
    "x": ["2020-03-14", "2020-03-26", "2020-03-27", "2020-04-02", "2020-04-06", "2020-04-09", "2020-04-14", "2020-04-17", "2020-04-18", "2020-04-20", "2020-04-22"],
    "y": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1],
    "xaxis": "x1",
    "yaxis": "y1",
    "type": "scatter"
},
    etc
]
```

However, the result appears to be one row with two columns that have all of the traces (there are 94 traces) squashed into them. Here is screenshot.

[image]

Any ideas what is happening? I expect to have 48 rows with 2 columns, one subplot per trace.

The only difference from the multiple subplots example is that my xaxis have date strings instead of numbers. Everything else is same.

Comment: try transforming each x into `Date`

Comment: tried `x.push(new Date(caseRegionByDate[i]['values'][j]['key']));` but no change

Comment: try this `new Date(newDate).getTime()` replacing x data

Comment: try add a big height to the container div

Comment: yes the charts are being drawn but are squashed vertically. I have since tried modifying `layout height:` to say 5000 which allows charts to be drawn visibly. But better would be, i am looking into setting each subplot height so it can be dynamic

Comment: You can change it dynamically based on the height 
document.getElementById("mycontainer").style.height = `${50*rows.length}px`;

Comment: Thanks that does work but looking for the "plotly.js" way to do this. This "small multiple" visualization should have some "plotly.js" solution out there but haven't found it yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The subplots are actually being created in 3 x rowCount grid. However they are all squashed vertically as in screenshot.

It appears that a chart's default height and width dimensions, where they are not explicitly defined using `layout.height`, are what is shown in my screenshot eg too small for 94 subplots.

The quick fix is to simply increase the chart's `layout.height` size. Then all subplots are visible. Dynamically calculating `layout.height`, in spirit of Juan's suggestion, relative to number of rows works well.

Apparently it is also possible to set each subplot's x and y domain attributes to resize subplots which will also give desired results.